# Split string between two symbols

Tags: c#, string, split

**I have the string:**

```
string myString = "^25121261064300000000000387?;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=25121261064338700000?";
```

I need split the string to get only the chain is within the symbols `;` and `=`.

**The expected result is** `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Any idea how separate between 2 symbols?

Comment: have you tried, for example, a regex? `\;(.*)\=` for example? or just two `string.IndexOf`? or... anything?

Comment: you should use the `string.Split() function along with the  string.Replace()` this is not that difficult

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say like below by splitting it two times on specific characters

```
string result = (myString.Split(';')[1]).Split('=')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Example 
{
   static void Main() 
   {
      string text = "^25121261064300000000000387?;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=25121261064338700000?";
      string pat = @"\;(.*)\=";

      Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

      Match m = r.Match(text);
      int matchCount = 0;
      while (m.Success) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Match"+ (++matchCount));
         for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) 
         {
            Group g = m.Groups[i];
            Console.WriteLine("Group"+i+"='" + g + "'");
            CaptureCollection cc = g.Captures;
            for (int j = 0; j < cc.Count; j++) 
            {
               Capture c = cc[j];
               System.Console.WriteLine("Capture"+j+"='" + c + "', Position="+c.Index);
            }
         }
         m = m.NextMatch();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I would not default to RegEx for a simple substring match. It is a general purpose pattern matcher, which means it's less likely to be efficient than algorithms tailored to the specific pattern at hand.

Comment: @Eric of course, the a counter to that is: most regex engines actually optimize pretty well for trivial scenarios... Not as efficient, sure; but not usually terrible

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'm sure you're right, and for 99+% of use cases either solution will work just fine. The code complexity of a RegEx solution and a tailored solution are similar, so I thought it worth mentioning for the sake of future visitors that might really benefit from a small performance edge.

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ by using [`SkipWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.100).aspx) methods:

```
string myString = "^25121261064300000000000387?;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=25121261064338700000?";
var result = string.Join("",myString.SkipWhile(c => c != ';')
                                    .Skip(1).TakeWhile(c=>c != '='));
```

OutPut:

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 1):

How come no one mentioned the **string.Split** method?

```
string[] splited = myString.Split(new char[] {'=', ';'});
```

The expected output should be at the middle of the array.